# changing/disabling color profile

Tags: display, system

I'm using a large TV as my monitor for elementary os. When I use spotify, It's too dark. In Ubuntu i could fix this by disabling the color profile through gnome settings. How can I do this in elementary? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `gnome-color-manager` to do that yourslef

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-color-manager
```

[image]
[image]